# Import a Gradle project into Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, import

I'm working on an android Project which i'd like to import another existing project developed with gradle. So, i've got successfully integrated that gradle project inside Eclipse. I've imported the gradle project and i can see and instantiate the classes from the gradle project, but when i launch the android project it throws the next log by the console:

```
 [2014-10-06 09:10:42 - Pdf2jpg-V3] Dx 
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:188)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:786)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:328)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:403)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:883)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
...while parsing simple/escp/Template.class

  [2014-10-06 09:10:43 - Pdf2jpg-V3] Dx 1 error; aborting
  [2014-10-06 09:10:43 - Pdf2jpg-V3] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

To import the gradle project to my android project i tried in two ways: 
1- Exporting a JAR from the gradle project and importing as external jar and checking it with the build path
2- adding the whole gradle project to the build path from the android project.

Both throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was the compliance level in the Gradle proeject (1.8), so, i updated the project to 1.6 (like my android project) and also updated the instances that were working only in 1.8 to be now working in 1.6.

My problem now is that it seems that the jar references included in the gradle project are not working, but in fact theay are included are gradle references as below:

[image: Gradle dependencies]

So, the execution throws class not found exception:

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.json.JsonObject
```

...Though javax.json is included, any idea??